# Why won't my datetime picker work?

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I am using code igniter, and I want to add a datetime picker using datetimepicker. The script can be found [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tengcalendar.shtml)

I have 2 sections on my webpage - the header and the content. On the controller, I load them both. Here is my javascript head

```
<script href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and here is my textbox code 
`<input id="tanggal" type="text" class="textbox" disabled="disabled"> <a href="javascript:NewCal('tanggal','ddmmyyyy')"><img src="<?php base_url(); ?>img/cal.gif"></a>`

when I refresh the page, I can hover the cal.gif, but when I click em, cal.gif is not responding. What went wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct way of including javascript files:

```
<script href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It should be:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/datetimepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep in mind, `base_url` allows to do this:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url('js/datetimepicker.js')?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```